# Adding Search (S) parameter to WP_Query gives Call to undefined function is_user_logged_in()

Tags: php, wordpress

Im creating a AJAX feature that needs to search posts.
Currently returning all like this works fine...

```
    $the_query = new WP_Query(
    array (
        'post_type'        => 'post',
        'posts_per_page'   => '10',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'orderby'          => 'title',
        'order'            => 'ASC',
    )
);
foreach($the_query->posts as $post):
  echo $post->post_title;
endforeach;
```

However when i add search with`s` parameter like below...

```
    $the_query = new WP_Query(
    array (
        's'                => 'mysearch',
        'post_type'        => 'post',
        'posts_per_page'   => '10',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'orderby'          => 'title',
        'order'            => 'ASC',
    )
);
foreach($the_query->posts as $post):
  echo $post->post_title;
endforeach;
```

I then get an error like

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_user_logged_in() in /wordpress/wp-includes/query.php on line 2084
```

Which is the core WP files, im not sure im doing search correctly? Will i have to use a `like` sql statement to get this? Or am i not doing it correctly?! This is for displaying it front end (non logged in / logged in users)

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem.

`$args = array(

```
'post_type' => 'block',
'posts_per_page' => -1
```

);

$get_all_block_posts = new WP_Query($args);`

Then I tried:

`    $args = array(

```
'post_type' => 'block',
'posts_per_page' => -1
```

);

$get_all_block_posts = get_posts($args);`

Comment: it seems that we i was unable to use WP_Query in the plugin.